# PWA set IOS status bar color with fixed header

Tags: html, css, ios, progressive-web-apps, statusbar

I already know you can use the combination of

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

and

```css
body {
    background-color: #014473;
}
```

to give the IOS status bar a custom color.

**The problem** I'm having is that I have a fixed header/navbar and as soon as I start scrolling further down the page, the status bar just keeps transparent and is displaying the page content.

I don't understand why they gave the status bar background an absolute position instead of a fixed one. I mean the *icons* like wifi, time and battery are still fixed so it would make sense that the background would be fixed as well.

[image: first][image: second]

Answer (score 0):

You can try change your viewport meta.
Your page will stretch to cover all of your screen.

```html
<meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,viewport-fit=cover"
    />
```

Comment: hmm, then I would have to push the whole navbar down

Answer (score 0):

Make your body fixed as well. But You have to have the height of the header fixed.

CSS for the header

```
position :fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
height:60px;
```

For the rest of the body create a new div and style as,

```
position :fixed;
top:60px;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
overflow: auto;
```